# Getting a "singleValue" image from aws CLI using "aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image"

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

In the AWS Console I have this metric visible:

[image]

I try to get the same image using the AWS CLI (using the json in the `Source` tab of Cloudwatch):

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image --metric-widget '{
    "metrics": [
        [ "AWS/ApiGateway", "Count", "ApiName", "MikeGw", "Resource", "/x/y", "Method", "POST", "Stage", "prod", { "stat": "Sum" } ]
    ],
    "view": "singleValue",
    "period": 300,
    "title": "Number of api calls",
    "setPeriodToTimeRange": true,
    "width": 1430,
    "height": 250,
    "start": "-PT3H",
    "end": "P0D"
}' | jq -r '.MetricWidgetImage' | base64 --decode >| image.png
```

and the result looks like this:

[image]

It seems to be ignoring `"view": "singleValue"`.

How do I get images that are just counts using this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single value widgets are not supported.

Since this is not really a graph, it's just a number, you can use the GetMetricData API to get this number and display it in some other way.

Alternatively, if you don't mind getting the graph, you can use the GetMetricWidgetImage API to get the full graph like you did and use dynamic labels on the graph to put the total number of calls in the graph legend. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/graph-dynamic-labels.html

This will give you the same graph you have in your question, but the label will be something like `[Sum: 11] Count` instead of just `Count`.